# Executing Queries in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

How do I execute a query using LINQ to SQL? a query that something goes like this.

Let's say I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Students
(
  StudentID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  Name SYSNAME
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.StudentLoans
(
  LoanID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  StudentID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Students(StudentID),
  Amount BIGINT -- just being funny
);
```

Then I wanted to execute this query.

```
DECLARE 
  @Name       SYSNAME = N'user962206', 
  @LoanAmount BIGINT = 50000,
  @StudentID  INT;

INSERT dbo.Students(Name) 
  SELECT @Name;

SELECT @StudentID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT dbo.StudentLoans(StudentID, Amount)
  SELECT @StudentID, @LoanAmount;
```

Is that possible? even if your Rows and Columns are mapped?  how can I execute that query with LINQ to SQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while, but wouldn't it be something like this?

Assuming you've dragged all your tables onto the Linq2Sql designer, simply create a `Student` object, add a `StudentLoan` to its `StudentLoans` collection, and add the `Student` to the `Context.Students` collection with `myContextInstance.Students.InsertOnSubmit(newStudent)` and write out the changes with a call to `myContextInstance.SubmitChanges`.

So, putting it all together:

```
using(var myContextInstance=new YourContext())
{
    var student = new Student(){Name = "user962206"};
    var studentLoan = new StudentLoan(){Amount = 50000};
    student.StudentLoans.Add(studentLoan);
    myContextInstance.Students.InsertOnSubmit(student);
    myContextInstance.SubmitChanges();
}
```

---

The code snippet works if your DataContext looks like this:

[image]

This is the result of just dragging your tables to the design surface of the dbml file.

Comment: I'm not  LINQ guy at all but how does the StudentLoans table populate the StudentID column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Linq2Sql knows about the FK relationship and is able therefore to manage the IDs of relationships. This part is effectively abstracted away.

Comment: Sounds like something I could have fun trying to break. :-) How does it do fare with self-referencing foreign keys?

Comment: Hah! It seems that L2S is pretty old-hat now. Entity framework is now in its 4th incarnation, and the rate of new developments there is pretty exciting. I've never tried to store trees/hierarchical data using Linq2BlaBla, but I'm fairly sure it would be a use-case considered by the dev team. It's really the expressivity of some kinds of joins that I miss the most... they can get quite dirty sometimes, but counter to that, because your data becomes an object model, it does away with many of the most common join scenarios.

Comment: @spender what do you mean newYourContext? is it like DataContext? sorry I am not familiar with the terms

Comment: Btw how I would manage this? How would I add a value to the foreign key? this is not working

Comment: @user962206 yes, it's meant to be the DataContext class generated by Linq2Sql when you drag tables on to the .dbml designer. Downvoter... please tell why?

Comment: @user962206 This is working code. Check your data context with the added image. The cool thing is that L2S enables us to work with objects in code without worrying about foreign keys.

Comment: @GetArnold where would I put that said code? in my form? or in the datacontext.designer.cs ?  sorry spender. there I upvoted

Comment: @spender where would I put the said code? in my WindowsForm cs? or Datacontext.designer.cs?  what if I'll I get the value from a textbox  how would I do that? can you show please me the full implementation? sorry kinda it is all kinda vague to me.

Comment: @user962206 : you should never put code in the designer generated files. The can get overwritten pretty easily. I think placing it in your form class would be a good start. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: @spender Once I place them in my Form class how would I actually use them? will I just insert that code? or I'll create a method for that? or I'll place it on an event?  I am kinda confuse since I am not familiar with  the keyword using. and why is it that in your said code there's student.StudentLoans.Add(studentLoan) what does it do?

Comment: @user962206 With the greatest respect, I think the scope of your questions has shifted sufficiently to open a new question, perhaps referring back to this one.

Comment: @spender okay thank you. btw will that code above will still work if I change the Data type of Name to varchar(50) ?

Answer (score 2):

If by your question you mean "how do a execute a raw SQL query with LINQ to SQL," then look at the `ExecuteCommand` and `ExecuteQuery` methods:

- ExecuteCommand -
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx
- ExecuteQuery (Overload 1) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534292.aspx
- ExecuteQuery (Overload 2) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx

All these methods take a raw SQL query, like yours, and runs it against the database

If you meant by your question "how do I write this SQL query as a LINQ query" then please clarify your question.

Comment: I mean " How do I execute a raw SQL query with LINQ to SQL"